# ¿Como mostrar el total de email enviados por una persona en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

Hola buen día comunidad espero que estén bien.
Soy bastante novato en terminos de MySQL y estoy aprendiendo hacer consultas un poco mas complejas y especificas espero que me puedan ayudar con sus conocimientos a resolver mi problema estaría realmente muy agradecido.
Mi problema es que tengo que hacer una consulta que me debe mostrar el total de los emails que son enviados de manera interna y el total de los emails que son enviados de manera externa por cada gerente. Para ser más claro mostrare un ejemplo corto de como es la tabla y explicar los campos.

- **codeGerente:** es el codigo distintivo de cada Gerente
- **esExtero:** 1-Indica que el email fue enviado de manera externa y 0-Indica que fue enviado de forma interna.
- **Estado:** 0-Error 1-EnvioCorrecto

| codeGerente | esExterno | Estado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ger2012 | 1 | 1 |
| ger2013 | 0 | 1 |
| ger2013 | 1 | 0 |
| ger2012 | 0 | 1 |
| ger2012 | 1 | 0 |

En base a eso la consulta debe de mostrar lo siguiente

| codeGerente | EmailExternoTotal | EmailInternoTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ger2012 | 1500 | 1200 |
| ger2013 | 600 | 1000 |
| ger2014 | 700 | 900 |
| ger2015 | 200 | 561 |
| ger2016 | 350 | 800 |

Tomado en cuenta que el Estado sea igual a 1 los que estén en Estado 0 no se deben de contabilizar.

Mi consulta es la siguiente

```html
SELECT 
    codeGerente AS gerente,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(esExterno)
        FROM
            envios
        WHERE
            esExterno = 1 AND estado = 1) AS Externo,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(esExterno)
        FROM
            envios
        WHERE
            esExterno = 0 AND estado = 1) AS Interno
FROM
    envios
GROUP BY codeGerente;
```

Y este es el resultado que me muestra

| Gerente | Externo | Interno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ger2012 | 50 | 12 |
| ger2013 | 50 | 12 |
| ger2014 | 50 | 12 |
| ger2015 | 50 | 12 |
| ger2016 | 50 | 12 |

De antemano agradezco por su tiempo y atención

**Nota**: Este es un ejercicio de escuela donde el profesor nos pidió hacerlo con subconsultas ya que ese es el tema.

Comment: ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Dónde está tu Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable del que se habla en el [tour] o [ask]?

Comment: Asier sería bueno que marcaras como aceptada la respuesta que te haya sido más útil, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
 T.codeGerente,
 sum(externo) as TotalExterno,
 sum(interno) as TotalInterno
from
(
 select
  codeGerente,
  case 
   when esExterno = 1 then 1
   else 0      
  end as externo,
  case 
   when esExterno = 0 then 1
   else 0      
  end as interno      
 from Tabla
 where estado = 1
) T
group by T.codeGerente
```

Se hace una **consulta interna** la cual filtra los registros cuyo **campo Estado** tenga el valor **1**, y haciendo uso del **case when** se proyecta la **columna externo** que tendrá como valor **1** si el **campo esExterno** tiene **1** como valor, caso contrario tendrá **0** como valor, se proyecta además la **columna interno** que tendrá como valor **1** si el **campo esExterno** tiene como valor **0**, caso contrario tendrá **0**. Sobre esta consulta se hará otra más general agrupando por el **campo codeGerente**, y proyectando el total correspondiente a las **columnas externo** e **interno**, obtenidas de la **consulta interior**.

Comment: no estás teniendo en cuenta el estado del email: si el envío ha sido correcto o con errores

Comment: @DavidJP si, yo puse un where en la consulta interna

Comment: Pues es resultado no cuadra... Ah, ya sé por qué, porque cuentas en vez de sumar

Comment: @DavidJP creo que sí, lo arreglo ahora, gracias

Comment: @DavidJP arreglado, ya debe funcionar, gracias

Comment: Muchas Japv tu respuesta me ayudo a resolver mi problema y es como dio DavidJP en vez contar hay que usar la función sum

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, aclarar que el dataset que aportas como ejemplo no se corresponde con los resultados que pretendes obtener.

Entendiendo que simplemente sea un ejemplo para que veamos el formato, te indico la consulta que podrías emplear:

```
SELECT codeGerente,
  SUM(esExterno AND Estado) EmailExternoTotal,
  SUM(NOT esExterno AND Estado) EmailInternoTotal
  FROM envios
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Para obtener los resultados:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| codeGerente | EmailExternoTotal | EmailInternoTotal |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| ger2012     |                 1 |                 1 |
| ger2013     |                 0 |                 1 |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

A partir del dataset en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE envios(
  codeGerente varchar(7),
  esExterno bool,
  Estado bool
  );

INSERT INTO envios VALUES
('ger2012',1,1),
('ger2013',0,1),
('ger2013',1,0),
('ger2012',0,1),
('ger2012',1,0);
```

El resultado que tú obtienes es fijo porque, aunque agrupes, siempre calculas los mismos totales. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y te la voy aclarando...

Comment: Muchas gracias David por tomarte el tiempo y compartir lo que sabes me ayuda a seguir aprendiendo y a comprender mejor las cosas. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: @AsierMiquelez Y curiosamente prefieres la otra respuesta que fue emitida más tarde, con errores (que hemos subsanado entre todos), que requiere una subconsulta (lo que la hace más ineficiente) y mucho más código. Por alguna razón te habrá gustado más, por favor, ilústranos...

Comment: Le respondo antes que nada le agradezco por el tiempo y atención. Para mi eso es  importante el ser agradecido con las personas que aportan de su tiempo y conocimiento para ayudar a otros.
Lo otro es porque era un ejercicio de escuela donde el profesor nos pidió hacerlo con subconsultas ya que ese es el tema.
Y le agradezco porque compartió otra forma de obtener el resultado la cual tendré presente

Comment: @DavidJP es cierto que tú respuesta es mejor por eso te vote positivo, por otra parte te agradezco me hayas ayudado a corregir el desliz que tuve, si pudiera darte otro voto positivo te lo daba, mis respetos

Comment: @AsierMiquelez @Japv Entiendo, en ese caso deberías modificar tu pregunta para que incluyera el condicionante de resolverlo necesariamente mediante una subconsulta. Tal y como ha quedado, has elegido arbitrariamente la mejor respuesta, y eso puede confundir a futuros usuarios. En cualquier caso, y esto ya va para tu profesor, las consultas deberían resolverse al mínimo coste computacional, si quería obligar a usar subconsultas, no tenía más que solicitar el gerente que más envíos realizara sin usar `ORDER BY`, precisamente por su alto coste computacional, y no hubiera quedado más opción.